# PostgreSQL: How to add data?

Tags: postgresql, etl

I have a table with the following columns:

```
col1 text,
col2 text,
col3 double precision,
col4 double precision,
col5 numeric
```

I need to keep there data like this:

```
text, "text2", "439, 86 [404]", "0,39", "0,11", "37,70%"
```

I use this command:

```
test=# COPY dataToImport2 FROM '/opt/DataToImport2.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv);
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "0,39"
CONTEXT:  COPY datatoimport2, line 1, column summaprodazhtyisrub: "0,39"
```

I understand that my mistakes are related to the characters "," and "%". If they are removed or replaced then all is well.

Can I write some kind of request to get this automatically?

Comment: The decimal separator in SQL is `.`not `,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COPY` cannot load only some of the columns of your input file.

There are several options:

- Preprocess the file outside PostgreSQL.
- Load the file as it is into a temporary table and post-process the contents.
- Use a third-party tool like pgLoader.

Comment: If I use the post-process option, do I need to write some kind of query that can convert the data or do I need to write these actions in the programming language (as in preprocess)?

Comment: You can usually do it with SQL statements unless you need some really complicated processing.